# Eclipse Kepler input issue

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm not sure whats wrong with the codes here:

```
package assigment1;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class A1Q2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int Level;
    int PureDiamonds;
    int ImpureDiamonds;


    System.out.print("Please enter the game level (1,2,3,4...): ");
    Level = input.nextInt();
```

It says `input cannot be resolved` and the thing is I have an old project with the `input.nextInt();` and it's working. So what's wrong? It's driving me crazy

Comment: Hint: Look at the variable name of your `Scanner`

Comment: There's nothing called "input".

Comment: Please consider that this Q/A site is no platform to help you debugging unless it is a very specific problem that affects a number of other users as well. BTW: the code `Level = input.nextInt()` has a syntax error, since there is no variable specified that the value is assigned to. Also try to find a meaningful title for you questions, since this is clearly no Eclipse issue!

Answer (score 0):

It's giving you that issue because `input` is not a variable in scope.

Assuming that you are trying to fetch input from the user, you need to use your `scan` object.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int Level;
    int PureDiamonds;
    int ImpureDiamonds;


    System.out.print("Please enter the game level (1,2,3,4...): "+ Level);
    Level = scan.nextInt(); // <-- this line.
```

One thing I wanted to point out, unrelative to your issue, is that you are using [PascalCase](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PascalCase) when Java is a [camelCase](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?CamelCase) language.. I'd recommend ridding of your possible C# idioms for consistencies sake! `:)`

Comment: im pretty sure i used to put input.nextInt(); instead of scan.nextInt(); lol maybe im wrong :P

Comment: then change the `Scanner scan = new Scanner(` to `Scanner input = new scanner(`

Answer (score 0):

Look at your variable names.  No where in your code have you declared a variable named 'input'.  You named your Scanner object 'scan'.

Try

```
 Level = scan.nextInt();
```

Also, even though it's syntactically 'legal', the proper Java naming convention for your variables is to begin them with a lower case letter.  By convention, class names begin with an upper case letter. This helps with the readability of your code.